# Change value1 & value 2 in URL in java

Tags: url

Running a API on localhost. First request sums up two values, 2nd request validates the input and decides if its a number and its length.
I need to test different values.
How can I test different (Lets say 5000 different values)?

```
package io.tester;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class JavaHttpUrlConnectionReader
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   throws Exception
   {
    new JavaHttpUrlConnectionReader();
   }
     public JavaHttpUrlConnectionReader()
   {
   try
     {
      String myUrl = "http://localhost:8080/add?value1=8&value2=4.2";
      String myUrl1 = "http://localhost:8080/validate?value=123";
      
      String results = doHttpUrlConnectionAction(myUrl);
      String results1 = doHttpUrlConnectionAction(myUrl1);
      System.out.println(results);
      System.out.println(results1);
      }
```

The output is -

> {"result":"12.2"}
>
> {"valueType":"small integer"}

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array and iterate through that array.

```
String[] numbers = {"1", "1.2","123","4","5"};

for(int i=0; i< numbers.length-1; i++)
{
    String myUrl = "http://localhost:8080/add?value1=" + numbers[i];
    String results = doHttpUrlConnectionAction(myUrl);
    System.out.println(results);
}
```